# Java XSD validator can't find element declaration

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema, sax

I have a simple schema validator method:

```
// Throws runtime exception if anything goes wrong.
public void validate(String schemaURL, String xml) throws Throwable {
    SAXParserFactory oSAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser oSAXParser = null;
    oSAXParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    SchemaFactory oSchemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    oSAXParserFactory.setSchema(oSchemaFactory.newSchema(new URL(schemaURL)));
    oSAXParser = oSAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
    SaxErrorHandler handler = new SaxErrorHandler();
    oSAXParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)),handler);
}
```

I have a schema hosted at `http://myserver.com/schemas/app-config/1.0/app-config-1.0.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="application">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="info"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="info">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Observe the follow instance of that schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://myserver.com/schemas/app-config/1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://myserver.com/schemas/app-config/1.0
        http://myserver.com/schemas/app-config/1.0/app-config-1.0.xsd">
    <info
        name="Dummy Application"
    />
</application>
```

When I pass my `validate` method the following:

```
String xmlInstance = readXMLIntoString();
String schemaURL = "http://myserver.com/schemas/app-config/1.0/app-config-1.0.xsd";

validate(schemaURL, xmlInstance);
```

I get the following error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'application'.

- Is something wrong with my schema?
- Is something invalid with my instance?
- Is there a problem with me actually hosting the schema at the URL (although the one used in this example is a mockup, I assure you that the XSD file really is hosted at the URL I'm hitting in the code)?

Why can't the validator find `application` declaration?

Comment: **Note:** I think one thing that people commonly get confused about is an XML namespace has NOTHING do to with an actual URL.  The reason that you see URLs being used is that it's a simple way to guarantee uniqueness.  I know that if I use my company's domain name for all my namespaces, it's not going to conflict with anyone else's namespaces.  Also, there's no rule that says that, if the namespace looks like a URL, that is actually has to be a valid URL.  It can just return a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer stated that schemaLocation was incorrect, which is in fact the case, but for a different reason than I suggested originally. As Kohányi Róbert said, your schema is missing a `targetNamespace`. Either follow his approach and modify your schema, or replace `schemaLocation` with `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation with lower letter IS correct, according to the XML spec. W3C validator validates the document as well-formed XML.

Comment: You are quite correct, I made the error of not checking whether schema validation actually triggered. I've updated my answer with the actual reason why `schemaLocation` does not work.

Comment: I removed my downvote accordingly. Now your answer makes sense ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're XML Schema is missing a *targetNamespace*.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://myserver.com/schemas/app-config/1.0"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
  ...
```

Instead of declaring a *targetNamespace* in your XML Schema you could drop all that *mumbo jumbo* from your XML.

```
<application>
  ...
```

Still, try to stick to the first solution.

Comment: Yes, it's Good Practice to always use namespaces in your XML.